# Cant get mysql procedure to work

Tags: mysql, nested, procedure

Variable captiono is not dynamic in BLOCK3. It is constant in BLOCK3 though is suppose to change while iterator2 loop.

```
           BLOCK2: BEGIN
      DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, caption FROM 
      mazhorik.catalog_items_content;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = TRUE;
      OPEN cur2;
        iterator2: LOOP
          IF done2 THEN
          LEAVE iterator2;
        END IF;
        FETCH cur2 INTO ido, captiono; 

                    BLOCK3: BEGIN
                    iterator3 : LOOP    
                    SET idoo = ido;
                    SET captionoo = captiono;
                    SET captionoo = REPLACE(captionoo, element, '');
                    SET camel =   CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(element, 1)), 
                    LCASE(SUBSTRING(element, 2)));


                    END LOOP iterator3;
                    END BLOCK3;
   END LOOP iterator2;
CLOSE cur2;
END BLOCK2;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=509fb3104ffbc49db325d24fd6020e4f).

Comment: wchiquito thank you for answer. You are right I wasnt specific enough. I changed code above in my question.